# Cannot upload any file on Magento 2.4, was able to upload earlier

Tags: magento2.4, upload

Image Upload very unstable, I am using Magento 2.4 community edition and in the Content block I am able to upload images some images while others are not working, all images are under 400kb and the size is like 570*570 px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly, set your website in developer mode and then try to upload image and at that time you have to check log in Magento_dir/var/log.

If this help then hit like.

Enjoy your coding !!! :)

Thank you
Hiren Patel